# How make a file preview for moodle documents in flutter

Tags: flutter, moodle

I am developing a mobile application for my school, which requires connecting to the website API with Moodle, the intention is to show the Moodle files from the same app, is there any way to do it?

So far, I can connect to the API, show the files, but the only solution I have achieved so far is to redirect to the browser so that the student can download the file.

Having the URL of the file, I thought about displaying the file via Google Docs, but in doing so, it tells me that the file cannot be displayed.

The URL I get from each file is type:

```
[moodle_site]/webservice/pluginfile.php/1504591/mod_resource/content/7/[file_name]?forcedownload=1&token=[token_user]
```

Any idea how to achieve it?